# SQL select from either one or other table

Tags: sql, select, db2

Assume I have a table A with a lot of records (> 100'000) and a table B with has the same columns as A and about the same data amount.
Is there a possibility with one clever select statement that I can either get all records of table A *or* all records of table B?

I am not so happy with the approach I currently use because of the performance:

```
select
     column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
from (
    select 'A' as tablename, a.* from table_a a
    union
    select 'B' as tablename, b.* from table_b b
) x
where 
    x.tablename = 'A'
```

Comment: Any reasons why the same type of data is in two separate tables?

Comment: Why not decide in your program which query to run?

Comment: `select * from table_a` ? I don't see a difference between changing the where clause and changing the from clause.

Comment: It's true that this query doesn't make sense without context. This query will be a subquery of another query (the parent query). Imagine tables A and B contain different data dependent on e.g. a country and I need to write a generic parent query which returns some specific data for any country just by changing the where clause e.g. to the country name.

Comment: The business decision to allow the data model to horizontally partition these tables based on set of columns is at the crux of your problem. If you can't merge these tables into a single table, I would suggest following the suggestion of @juergend to put logic in the application (or stored procedure) to decide which table to query.

Comment: I cannot involve any programming etc. the restriction is to use pure (DB2) sql.

Comment: Would a stored procedure that returns a table be acceptable?  Something you could call inline?

Answer (score 3):

Offhand, your approach seems like the only approach in standard SQL.

You will improve performance considerably by changing the `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  The `UNION` must read in the data from both tables and then eliminate duplicates, before returning any data.

The `UNION ALL` does not eliminate duplicates.  How much better this performs depends on the database engine and possibly on turning parameters.

Actually, there is another possibility.  I don't know how well it will work, but you can try it:

```
select *
from ((select const.tableName, a.*
       from A cross join
            (select 'A' as tableName where x.TableName = 'A')
      ) union all
      (select const.tableName, b.*
       from B cross join
            (select 'B' as tableName where x.TableName = 'B')
      )
     ) t
```

No promises.  But the idea is to cross join to a table with either 1 or 0 rows.  This will not work in MySQL, because it does not allow `WHERE` clauses without a `FROM`.  In other databases, you might need a tablename such as `dual`.  This gives the query engine an opportunity to optimize away the read of the table entirely, when the subquery contains no records.  Of course, just because you give a SQL engine the opportunity to optimize does not mean that it will.

Also, the "*" is a bad idea particularly in union's.  But I've left it in because that is not the focus of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your hints! I will definitely use "union all". Thanks also your alternative suggestion, I will have a lookt at it.

Answer (score 2):

you can try next solution, it's selects only from table tmp1 ('A' = 'A')

```
select
  *
from
  tmp1
where
  'A' = 'A'

union all

select
  *
from
  tmp2
where
  'B' = 'A'
```

SQL Fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1051/17/0)
check execution plan

[image: plan]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what you want without a little more context, but perhaps something like this could work?

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(15);
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(50);

SELECT @TableName = YourField
FROM YourTable
WHERE ...

SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName

EXEC @Query
```

Syntax might differ a bit depending on what RDBMS you are using, and more specifically what you are trying to accomplish, but might be a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this *and* maintain performance requires some modification to your physical table design.

If you can add a column to each table that holds your indicator column and add a check constraint on that column, you can achieve "partition" elimination on your query.

DDL:

```
create table table_a (
   c1 ...
  ,c2 ...
  ,c3 ...
  ,table_ind char(1) not null generated always as 'A'
  ,constraint ck_table_ind check (table_ind = 'A')
);

create table table_b (
   c1 ...
  ,c2 ...
  ,c3 ...
  ,table_ind char(1) not null generated always as 'B'
  ,constraint ck_table_ind check (table_ind = 'B')
);

create view v1 as (
    select * from table_a 
    union all 
    select * from table_b
);
```

If you execute the query `select c1,c2,c3 from v1 where table_ind = 'A'` the DB2 optimizer will use the check constraint to recognize that no rows in `table_b` can match the `table_ind = 'A'` predicate, so it will completely eliminate the table from the access plan.

This was used (and still is in some cases) before DB2 for Linux/UNIX/Windows supported Range Partitioning.  You can read more about this technique in this [research paper [PDF]](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0202zuzarte/0202zuzarte.pdf) written by some of the IBM DB2 developers back in 2002.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have only read access to the tables so I cannot modify the table creation as you suggested. The queries that I have to write are purely for data evaluation.

Comment: OK, but if you have performance issues you really should work with your DBA to get a proper physical design.